# Is it possible to check which RPC APIs are available?

Tags: web3js, dapp-development, cors, json-rpc

Is it possible for a decentralized application to get details about the offered JSON-RPC APIs from the local ethereum node?

I want to check the following specs in the following order using `web3.js`:

1. Is the RPC port open and listening at `:8545`?
2. Is the RPC set to allow CORS requests from my domain (`example.com`)?
3. Which RPC APIs are availabe by the client (`db,eth,net,web3`)?

Is the 2nd step even possible if CORS is disabled for my remote domain? Will a disabled CORS RPC port be discoverable? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 and 2 can be checked with web3.isConnected()

3. You can only use web3 with web3.js

You can't check these if you don't have cors for your domain because you can't access the rpc without it

Comment: but can 1 and 2 be checked independently?

Comment: AFAIK makes no sense to check 2 via web3.js, if the response was false, you would not be able to ask.

Comment: FYI as of yesterday, there is this https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3_extended  which brings you admin and debug through js. Use with extreme caution.

Comment: as of yesterday @tjade273 published https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3_ipc which is a fork that adds IPC support