# How can I make new account by JSON-RPC?

Tags: go-ethereum, security, json-rpc

I'd like to make new account by JSON-RPC.I've checked the wiki of [Ethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_accounts), however I could not find out how to do that.

I've found call existed accounts, but it isn't what I want. 

`eth_accounts`

Could you tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### First, a note on safety:

**You should not make the `personal` API available over RPC**

If you are on a local, trusted machine, you should use IPC instead of RPC. Otherwise, anyone who can connect to your node via RPC can try to brute-force your passwords and steal your Ether.

All administrative APIs are available by default over IPC, so no need to use any flags with geth

#### To connect via IPC:

Install my library:
`npm install web3_extended`

```
var web3_extended = require('web3_extended');

var options = {
  host: '/home/user/.ethereum/geth.ipc',
  ipc:true,
  personal: true, 
  admin: false,
  debug: false
};

var web3 = web3_extended.create(options);

web3.personal.newAccount("password",function(error,result){
    if(!error){
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

Replace the `host` variable with the proper path for your system.

Note: All requests via IPC must be asynchronous.

---

#### Some Alternatives:

I don't know why you want to create new accounts via web3, but it's likely not the best way to do what you're trying to achieve. It is much safer and more modular to use a [hooked web3 provider](https://github.com/ConsenSys/hooked-web3-provider) with a client-side [light wallet](https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet) or to simply use the [Mist browser](https://github.com/ethereum/mist) which handles all accounts for you.

#### Now for the technique (don't do this)

You need to enable the `personal` API over RPC. Do this by starting geth with

`geth --rpc --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,personal"`

Then you can use the `personal_newAccount` method via RPC. It's not implemented in web3.js, so you need to manually issue the RPC request. For example with curl:

`curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"personal_newAccount","params":["password"],"id":1}' localhost:8545`

creates a new account with password `password` and returns the address:

`{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"0x05ca0ddf7e7506672f745b2b567f1d33b7b55f4f"}`
There is some [basic documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Go-ethereum-management-API%27s#personal_unlockAccount)

**Alternatively:**
Use the unofficial [extended web3.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3_extended)

- this allows you to use the `personal`, `admin` and `miner` APIs via a standard web3.js interface.

Comment: Hmm, actually it looks like the web3.js library doesn't implement `personal` functions, even over IPC. Give me a minute to hack something together.

Comment: @toshikaseda I forked the web3_extended library to allow IPC connections.  https://github.com/tjade273/web3_extended

Comment: Thx, I'll check it!

Comment: You can now install with `npm install web3_ipc`

Comment: see related question - http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/784/is-it-possible-to-check-which-rpc-apis-are-available

Comment: @TjadenHess You mentioned "/home/user/.ethereum/geth.ipc". Should I make geth.ipc by myself? Or is it still existed?

Comment: It should already exist in whatever datadirectory you're using

Comment: @TjadenHess I'd like to call geth from ruby, not javascript. Could you tell me how can I do that, if I cannot use JSON-RPC?

Comment: Well, I've created a PR to merge web3_ipc into web3_extended, but there's been no reply. These tools really aren't supposed to be exposed by web3, so idk if merging them would be smart

Comment: Why not merge with web3 and include a warning?

Comment: @TjadenHess how can I  unlock account using private key instead of password into json rpc

Answer (score 1):

In [ethereum-php/ethereum.php](https://github.com/btelle/ethereum-php) add

`function personal_newAccount($passphase)
{
  return $this->ether_request(__FUNCTION__, array($passphase));
}`

and call it to create new account

Comment: btelle/ethereum-php is hopelessly outdated.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, i think you are using testrpc of ganache to do this.
If you are using python to do this. It is very simple. 
First you need to install web3. Type in the following in the terminal

```
pip install web3
```

(make sure you are using python 3.5 or above.)
Now open python console in the terminal by typing in `python` in the terminal. Once you are in the python console, type in

```
from web3 import Web3
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545"))
web3.newAccount('1234')
```

Here '1234' is the passcode that is required to create the ethereum account. If you do not provide the passcode, you will be prompted to do so.
If you are not using testrpc or ganache, you should change the HTTPProvider to some other providers as instructed [here](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/providers.html)