# When is the geth.ipc file produced?

Tags: go-ethereum, ipc

I'd like to access geth.ipc file in order to connect geth via IPC.
I've got an [advice](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/how-can-i-make-new-account-by-json-rpc) and it suggested me to access geth.ipc, but I've not found it on my mac.
Could you tell me when that file is produced? Btw, I installed go-ethereum by git as follows.

`git clone https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum`

The image shows my Ethereum directory. Doesn't it contain geth.ipc right?
[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The IPC file is only present when Geth is actually running. So be sure to start Geth and you should see a message like.

`I0219 09:45:48.128503 node/node.go:290] IPC endpoint opened: /Users/username/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc`

The location displayed here depends on your operating system. These are the other options.

**macOS**

`~/Library/Ethereum/`

**Linux**

`~/.ethereum/`

**Windows**

`~/AppData/Roaming/Ethereum`

Comment: Thx Maran. But, I cannot find it on ~/Library/Ethereum. Could you tell me when the dierectory(~/Library/Ethereum) was installed? When I did `git clone https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum`?

Comment: Did you run Geth yet? It needs to be run in order to create the folders.

Comment: I did. It seems that, because I didn't update ethereum, the geth.ipc didn't exist on my mac. Now, I'm running brew upgrade.

Comment: I've updated question.I've checked Ethereum directory after `brew update && brew upgrade` and  `brew update && brew reinstall ethereum` . However, it contains geth.ipc. Should I reinstall Ethereum?

Comment: Please start Geth and keep it running. The file should be there.

Comment: The data for Windows is wrong, that folder is used to store the blockchain data. But the correct path for ipc is `\\.\pipe\geth.ipc`.

Answer (score 10):

IPC is short for [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) and is no standard file in your installation or environment but rather a [domain socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket).

After you installed `geth` the ipc socket is not automatically created and its also not considerable a permanent resource.

The `geth.ipc` socket only exists as long as `geth` is *running*. You can specify the ipc path with the `--ipcpath "/path/to/my/geth.ipc"` flag. You can control the available apis with the `--ipcapi` flag. You can disable IPC with `--ipcdisable`. From `geth --help`:

```
--ipcdisable                            Disable the IPC-RPC server
--ipcapi "admin,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3"   API's offered over the IPC-RPC interface
--ipcpath "geth.ipc"                        Filename for IPC socket/pipe within the datadir (explicit paths escape it)
```

Read more on the go-ethereum wiki [on management apis](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Go-ethereum-management-API's).

Comment: `geth attach ipc:path/to/geth.ipc`
Not sure if `--ipcpath` flag still works

Comment: geth attach <path of ipc>

Comment: It looks like this is the actual correct answer. This file is not a permanent file but a socket and does not exist as a file. At least not on a macOS file system. I have looked everywhere in my system including invisible files and it does not exist. I am currently running geth. Can anyone confirm that this file actually does not reside on the filesystem?

Comment: @tymac I can confirm that this is consistent with what I've observed on my mac.

Comment: @FugueWeb `geth attach` connects to a remote geth instance. I have no .ipc file since geth somehow refuses to create it... I need it to create this rendezvous/socket file. And `geth attach` gives simply this (path is not important as I have no other geth instance): `Fatal: Unable to attach to remote geth: dial unix path/to/geth.ipc: connect: no such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

For window10,

the path is in format \.\pipe\xxxxx.ipc

If you have this in your config.toml

```
[Node]
IPCPath = "geth.ipc"
```

you could do

```
geth_windows.exe attach \\.\pipe\geth.ipc
```