# geth attach not working on osx, problem with geth.ipc?

Tags: mining, console

According to [this information](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/1908), I should be able to `attach` to `geth` with the following command on my OSX machine:

```
geth attach ipc://somePath/geth.ipc
```

in consideration of what to do about that "somePath", I attempted to follow the advice [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/when-is-the-geth-ipc-file-produced/1493), and use:

```
~/Library/Ethereum/
```

However, when I run the command:

```
 geth attach ipc:~/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc
```

I get the following error message:

```
Fatal: Unable to attach to remote geth: dial unix ~/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc: connect: no such file or directory
```

Also tried

```
geth attach --ipcdisable
```

which resulted in this:

[image]

Ultimately what I'd like to do is connect to the geth console without it spewing out a bunch of text so that I can examine the account balance of my address for my testnet mining, like I was asking about [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/22966/how-to-check-if-my-testnet-geth-node-has-mined-some-ether).

Any ideas about what's wrong with my `geth.ipc` or how I can check that address would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or you can do it like this:

```
geth attach ipc:/Users/s.matthew.english/Library/Ethereum/testnet/geth.ipc
```

the `geth.ipc` file location is displayed like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

got it :D

need to start with `geth --verbosity 0 console --port "35555"`, as I've done here:

[image]

seems to be something particular to OSX