# Create a new contract by JSON-RPC of cpp-ethereum

Tags: json-rpc, contract-deployment, cpp-ethereum

I want to create a new contract by JSON-RPC and cpp-ethereum.

I find out  **eth_sendTransaction** can help me to do this.

And let do it, I need to set "to" parameter like that:

```
to: DATA, 20 Bytes - (optional when creating new contract) The address the transaction is directed to.
```

But when I try to work on it with sample code with port 8079(own setup):

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_sendTransaction","params":[{
  "from": "0x009fbfed8d5ca3b7c1fe680e1dd61fc726ef177b",
  "to": "0x005fecaea1b18f5247fdb457793f3da72df12e61",
  "gas": "0x76c0",
  "gasPrice": "0x9184e72a000",
  "value": "0x9184e72a",
  "data": "0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8d46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f072445675058bb8eb970870f072445675"}],"id":1}' http://localhost:8079
```

I received nothing from above command.

I also know another way to create a new contract by solidity.

But I really want to use only JSON-RPC API.

Please give me advise to create a new contract by this way.

Answer (score 2):

### Summary

- You cannot include the `to:` field in your JSON-RPC `eth_sendTransaction` message.
- Check that your account is not locked

---

### Let's Find Out What Data Is Required

I'm using `geth` and JavaScript with the example [Syntax for calling contract state changing methods](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/7558/1268) to work out the data required.

Here is my `geth` command line:

```
user@Kumquat:~$ geth --datadir ~/EtherDev/data --dev \
  --mine --minerthreads 1 --verbosity 3              \
  --unlock 0 --password ~/EtherDev/etc/passwordfile  \
  --rpc console
```

(Note that I have unlocked my account, and this may be one of the reasons why your contract creation transaction failed. See [Can I unlock an account using JSON-RPC?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2278/can-i-unlock-an-account-using-json-rpc) for further information.)

And then run the following commands:

```
> var cSource='contract C { uint[] public numbers; function initNumbers() { numbers.push(1); numbers.push(2); } function stateChanger(uint a) { numbers.push(a); }      }'
undefined
> var cCompiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(cSource);
Version: 0.3.5-0/RelWithDebInfo-Linux/g++/Interpreter

path: /usr/bin/solc
undefined
> var cContract = web3.eth.contract(cCompiled.C.info.abiDefinition);
undefined
// Turn up the debugging to view the intermediate information
> debug.verbosity(7)
null
> var c = cContract.new({
    from:web3.eth.accounts[0], 
    data: cCompiled.C.code, gas: 400000}, 
    function(e, contract) {
      if (!e) {
        if (!contract.address) {
          console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + 
            contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");
        } else {
          console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);
          console.log(contract);
        }
    }
})
...
I0731 00:16:36.230020 core/tx_pool.go:547] removed tx (
    TX(46f833281c8c7652c0734773723e61fc5b6d2cbe731024ff730e4d2626d39b59)
    Contract: false
    From:     a7857047907d53a2e494d5f311b4b586dc6a96d2
    To:       [contract creation]
    Nonce:    37
    GasPrice: 20000000000
    GasLimit  400000
    Value:    0
    Data:     0x6060604052610164806100126000396000f3606060405260e060020a60003504635a7dc89781146100315780636506077514610074578063d39fa233146100aa575b005b61002f600080546001810180835582818380158290116100f8578183600052602060002091820191016100f891905b808211156101395760008155600101610060565b61002f60043560008054600181018083558281838015829011610152578183600052602060002091820191016101529190610060565b6100e6600435600080548290811015610002575080527f290decd9548b62a8d60345a988386fc84ba6bc95484008f6362f93160ef3e563015481565b60408051918252519081900360200190f35b50505060009283525060208220600191018190558154908101808355828183801582901161013d5781836000526020600020918201910161013d9190610060565b5090565b50505060009283525060209091206002910155565b5050506000928352506020909120015556
    V:        0x1b
    R:        0x6726a5204268ea430c32087f6ce85750f51e6792dd55139d3e3c7f9ce6d19812
    S:        0x3fb400f4bb13ad95dfa03023e42ee91aade477aa8ed921f5111b666753d60b3
    Hex:      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
) from pool: low tx nonce or out of funds
...
Contract mined! Address: 0x2bdd1725a5cdf212d6dfaa488ae2cecbe7b1dc1f
```

### Let's Try Sending The Contract Creation Transaction With JSON-RPC

I'm using `geth` rather than cpp-ethereum as I don't have cpp-ethereum configured, but the JSON-RPC should be the same. I'm using port 8545 for the JSON-RPC port.

I removed the `to:` field with a copy of your JSON-RPC call, and added the data from my debugging trace.

Here is my first attempt:

```
user@Kumquat:~$ curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_sendTransaction","params":[{
>   "from": "0xa7857047907d53a2e494d5f311b4b586dc6a96d2",
>   "gas": "0x76c0",
>   "gasPrice": "0x9184e72a000",
>   "value": "0",
>   "data": "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"}],"id":1}' http://localhost:8545
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"Intrinsic gas too low"}}
```

I bumped up `gas:` and removed `gasPrice:`. Following is my second attempt:

```
user@Kumquat:~$ curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_sendTransaction","params":[{
>   "from": "0xa7857047907d53a2e494d5f311b4b586dc6a96d2",
>   "gas": "0x776c0",
>   "value": "0",
>   "data": "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"}],"id":1}' http://localhost:8545
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"0x938040c15d0cabe9a9dbb1b629156cd9184c32e0538fc9159450bb5c056f4be4"}
```

A transaction hash has been returned - looking good. Let's see what the `geth` console shows:

```
I0731 00:53:16.024486 core/tx_pool.go:547] removed tx (
    TX(938040c15d0cabe9a9dbb1b629156cd9184c32e0538fc9159450bb5c056f4be4)
    Contract: false
    From:     a7857047907d53a2e494d5f311b4b586dc6a96d2
    To:       [contract creation]
    Nonce:    40
    GasPrice: 20000000000
    GasLimit  489152
    Value:    0
    Data:     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
    V:        0x1b
    R:        0xb57458702e0d4033cd52bbdf8c458639a5fed2359189ccd18e19be274c14ba19
    S:        0x3dcfaae9b58268d5aea27250719930e60c2213382e4b50355c7f72b248e34596
    Hex:      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
) from pool: low tx nonce or out of funds
```

Let's get the newly created contract address (you can use the [JSON-PC web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgettransactionreceipt)):

```
> eth.getTransactionReceipt("938040c15d0cabe9a9dbb1b629156cd9184c32e0538fc9159450bb5c056f4be4")
{
  blockHash: "0xe5884a160ffc2e9d88219e2638ed772abbfcc6b5ab272e66881803794baf4dce",
  blockNumber: 559,
  contractAddress: "0x5e792e0af19475caee3ff242bb58edda4b455eac",
  cumulativeGasUsed: 115811,
  from: "0xa7857047907d53a2e494d5f311b4b586dc6a96d2",
  gasUsed: 115811,
  logs: [],
  root: "7750bdc145e773d42f5cabbd1b97bfab45a53ba7f3b2b08762446fd44ab0f2d5",
  to: null,
  transactionHash: "0x938040c15d0cabe9a9dbb1b629156cd9184c32e0538fc9159450bb5c056f4be4",
  transactionIndex: 0
}
```

Let's check the code at the contract address:

```
> eth.getCode("0x5e792e0af19475caee3ff242bb58edda4b455eac")
"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"
```

Success! A new contract has been created using the JSON-RPC `eth_sendTransaction` API. This same JSON-RPC API should work with cpp-ethereum.

---

### What Happens If You Include `to:` In The Data Sent

I tested what happens if you include the `to:` field with the JSON-RPC `sendTransaction`.

Here's the request and the resulting transaction hash:

```
user@Kumquat:~$ curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_sendTransaction","params":[{
  "from": "0xa7857047907d53a2e494d5f311b4b586dc6a96d2",
  "to": "0x005fecaea1b18f5247fdb457793f3da72df12e61",
  "gas": "0x776c0",
  "value": "0",
  "data": "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"}],"id":1}' http://localhost:8545
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"0xa92bbeee20563c239715b2956a755fa3fdabe7e5eaba1de6652a96360fa799be"}
```

Here's the transaction information:

```
> eth.getTransaction("0xa92bbeee20563c239715b2956a755fa3fdabe7e5eaba1de6652a96360fa799be")
{
  blockHash: "0x3aa9ba9513d881903079e7eaceb08dcd2db933d2f5ac6aa9f11d8626a006ab6d",
  blockNumber: 613,
  from: "0xa7857047907d53a2e494d5f311b4b586dc6a96d2",
  gas: 489152,
  gasPrice: 20000000000,
  hash: "0xa92bbeee20563c239715b2956a755fa3fdabe7e5eaba1de6652a96360fa799be",
  input: "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",
  nonce: 41,
  to: "0x005fecaea1b18f5247fdb457793f3da72df12e61",
  transactionIndex: 0,
  value: 0
}
```

And here's the transaction receipt information:

```
> eth.getTransactionReceipt("0xa92bbeee20563c239715b2956a755fa3fdabe7e5eaba1de6652a96360fa799be")
{
  blockHash: "0x3aa9ba9513d881903079e7eaceb08dcd2db933d2f5ac6aa9f11d8626a006ab6d",
  blockNumber: 613,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 44512,
  from: "0xa7857047907d53a2e494d5f311b4b586dc6a96d2",
  gasUsed: 44512,
  logs: [],
  root: "71bd24394df7c5feb534b7e6081af0550e2b58c552002c03550ec3fc64a520c6",
  to: "0x005fecaea1b18f5247fdb457793f3da72df12e61",
  transactionHash: "0xa92bbeee20563c239715b2956a755fa3fdabe7e5eaba1de6652a96360fa799be",
  transactionIndex: 0
}
```

**Including the `to:` field results in a regular transaction, not a contract creation transaction**

---

### What Happens When Your Account Is Locked

Here's the response:

```
user@Kumquat:~/EtherDev$ curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_sendTransaction","params":[{
>   "from": "0xa7857047907d53a2e494d5f311b4b586dc6a96d2",
>   "gas": "0x776c0",
>   "value": "0",
>   "data": "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"}],"id":1}' http://localhost:8545
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"account is locked"}}
```

Comment: If i have cContract.new(savedataIncontract , address, {
    from:web3.eth.accounts[0], 
    data: cCompiled.C.code, gas: 400000},  like of syntax on that case how can i write RPC request