# Understanding nameReg.call("register", "MyName") style call between contracts

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, abi, fallback-function

Here's an example from solidity [docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#address) on **Address** type methods(**`call`** method specifically):

> address nameReg = 0x72ba7d8e73fe8eb666ea66babc8116a41bfb10e2;
>
> nameReg.call("register", "MyName");
>
> nameReg.call(bytes4(sha3("fun(uint256)")), a);

I can't understand what the second line does. Does it call the fallback function with these two arguments? Or does it pass string **MyName** to function **register** on **nameReg** contract?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [link in the question](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#address), the important part about `nameReg.call("register", "MyName")` is (bold mine):

> **to interface with contracts that do not adhere to the ABI**, the
>   function `call` is provided which takes an arbitrary number of arguments
>   of any type. These arguments are padded to 32 bytes and concatenated.

See the [note here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/1171/42):

> Note: the ABI is an abstraction that is not part of the core Ethereum
>   protocol. Anyone can define their own ABI for their contracts, and any
>   callers of such contracts would have to comply with that ABI to get
>   meaningful results. However, it is simpler for all developers to use
>   Solidity, Serpent, and web3.js which all comply with the ABI above.

`nameReg.call("register", "MyName")` **will not invoke `register` on a `nameReg` contract compiled by Solidity.**  The reason is that Solidity does not use "register" to lookup "functions" (it uses the first 4 bytes as the method id. For example EVM pseudocode that Solidity produces, see [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7973/how-is-an-abi-stored-in-bytecode)).  Here's code for a [quick test](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2835/how-to-quickly-test-a-solidity-function):

```
contract NameReg {
    bytes32 public nn;
    bytes public calldata;

    function register(bytes32 name) {
      nn = name;    
    }

    function() {
        calldata = msg.data;
    }

    function doesNotCallRegister() {
        this.call("register", "MyName");
    }
 }
```

With a`nameReg` contract compiled by Solidity, `nameReg.call("register", "MyName")` will invoke the fallback function where `msg.data` will be "register", "MyName" padded to 32 bytes and concatenated: `0x72656769737465720000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004d794e616d650000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`.

Comment: fallback function stores msg.data to calldata. Is it mutating the state?
Is 2300 gas enough for that when the fallback function invoked?

Comment: @kk-dev11 Yes the fallback function in this case mutates state and costs more than 2300 gas.  But invoking `nameReg.call("register", "MyName")` will pass more gas: it's a `.call` and see Case 2 of https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/5993/42

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet is building on one of the [example contracts](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html?highlight=namereg#inheritance) on the Contracts page in the Solidity documentation:

```
contract NameReg {
    function register(bytes32 name);
    function unregister();
}
```

So:

> Or does it pass string MyName to function register on nameReg
>   contract?

Yes.