# What does Solidity's "call" function mean?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, dapp-development, abi, fallback-function

```
address nameReg = 0x72ba7d8e73fe8eb666ea66babc8116a41bfb10e2;
nameReg.call("register", "MyName"); //1
nameReg.call(bytes4(sha3("fun(uint256)")), a); //2
if(!nameReg.call.value(10)){throw;} //3
```

[Here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#address) it says,

> Furthermore, to interface with contracts that do not adhere to the
>   ABI, the function call is provided which takes an arbitrary number of
>   arguments of any type. These arguments are padded to 32 bytes and
>   concatenated. One exception is the case where the first argument is
>   encoded to exactly four bytes. In this case, it is not padded to allow
>   the use of function signatures here.

- Are 1 and 2 legal?
- Does it mean that 2  is illegal?
- What does the 3 mean?

Answer (score 23):

Solidity's `call` is a **low-level interface for sending a message to a contract.**  It returns `false` if the subcall encounters an exception, otherwise it returns `true`.  There is no notion of a legal call, if it compiles, it's valid Solidity.

1. `nameReg.call("register", "MyName")` is a message that passes certain bytes to nameReg.  For the bytes, see: [Understanding nameReg.call("register", "MyName") style call between contracts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8168/understanding-namereg-callregister-myname-style-call-between-contracts)
2. `nameReg.call(bytes4(sha3("fun(uint256)")), a)` is a message that would invoke a function named `fun` (if nameReg adheres to the ABI) and pass it the raw, unpadded data `a` (you need to correctly pad `a` to 32 bytes first if you want behavior to match the [ABI](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/234/what-is-an-abi-and-why-is-it-needed-to-interact-with-contracts).  For `uint256` use left-padding.).

For 3, `contract.call.value(...)(...)` is a [way to add Ether](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/frequently-asked-questions.html#what-does-p-recipient-call-value-p-amount-p-data-do) when invoking a contract.  `if(!nameReg.call.value(10)()){throw;}` is an example of handling the failure case of the subcall.  Note the extra parentheses `value(10)()` which invokes the fallback function.

`call` is a low-level interface, and it is simpler to invoke a function directly, `nameReg.fun(a)` instead of the second example.  The direct invocation is also type-safe, and allows the return value of `fun` to be used.

Comment: Note that in the case of 1, `"register"` and `"MyName"` are padded to 32 bytes, whereas in 2, `a` is concatenated directly onto the 4-byte `bytes4(sha3("fun(uint256)"))`

Comment: @eth so do you mean it ignores returned value by the contract?

Comment: @user2284570 Yes, Solidity's `call` does not return a contract function's return value: it only returns did the function encounter an exception or not.

Comment: As I understand it, `(bool success, bool returnBytes) = addr.call{...}(abi.encodeWithSignature(...), ...)` is the new recommended way to (1) call functions without throwing if the function cannot be called, and (2) send payment to payable functions. So I'm pretty sure chriseth's comment about `call` only applies to the older versions.

Comment: @LukeHutchison Think you're right, upvoted, and removed the chriseth comment. Not sure how much to edit the rest of this answer; feel free to write a 2nd answer that is much more current :)