# When a contract calls another contracts, can it return values?

Tags: contract-development, transactions, web3js, contract-invocation

When a contract calls another contract, are values returned ? I've seen things like:

```
function foo() external returns (bool success) {
    if( ... ) throw;
    return true;
}
```

But have read that calls to other contracts return either `false` if the call fails, or `true` if the call succeeds, meaning the `returns (bool success)`and `return true`are redundant.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a contract will get the return value when it invokes another contract in the usual way, as in `address.foo()`.

What you have read about, is the use of [Solidity's lower-level `call` function](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8270/what-does-soliditys-call-function-mean) [example: `address.call(bytes4(sha3('foo()')))`], which will not return the value from `foo`.

`return true` may seem redundant, but it is helpful when using web3.js to invoke `foo`.  With web3.js, one could use `web3.eth.call` first to invoke `foo`.  If `true` is obtained, then invoke `foo` with `web3.eth.sendTransaction`.  Had the `return true` not been included in the source code of `foo`, this technique would not be possible.

Supplementary information: [What is the difference between a transaction and a call?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call)