# Does returned success condition for low level calls imply call reverted or not?

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation

Can't find much info in the solidity docs (https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.7.6/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=call) pertaining to what the returned success condition of low level calls would imply (i.e. does it mean call reverted or not?).

I.e. for a low level `call` the docs state:

```
<address>.call(bytes memory) returns (bool, bytes memory)

issue low-level CALL with the given payload, returns success condition and return data, forwards all available gas, adjustable
```

So, does the returned success condition imply the call reverted? Or does it mean the method of which was attempted to be called doesn't exist and/or the call returned 0 bytes of data?

i.e.

```
    (bool success,) = address(<address>).call(<method sig>);
    if(success) {
        //if success == true does that mean call *did not* revert?
    } else {
        //if success == false does that mean call *reverted*?
    }
```

Comment: See this topic: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8270/what-does-soliditys-call-function-mean