# Why do statically compiled calls and addr.call(data) work differently when recipient has no fallback?

Tags: solidity

I always thought these two calls were equivalent:

```
Receiver(r).onTokenReceived(a, u);

r.call(bytes4(sha3("onTokenReceived(address,uint256)")), a, u);
```

It turns out they both work if the receiver has `onTokenReceived(a,u)`, and they both work if the receiver has a fallback function. But if the receiver has no fallback function defined, the first line fails with `invalid opcode`, but the second line runs without error! Why is this?

Here's my full test code. Only test5 fails.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.13;

contract Receiver {
    event Log(address addr, uint val);
    function onTokenReceived(address from, uint val) 
    returns (bool) {
        Log(from, val);
        return true;
    }
}

contract FallbackReceiver {
    event Log(uint x);
    function () {
        Log(uint8(msg.data[0]));
    }
}

contract NonReceiver {}

contract Sender {
    Receiver rec = new Receiver();
    address fallbackRec = address(new FallbackReceiver());
    address nonRec = address(new NonReceiver());
    address a = 0x1;
    uint u = 1;

    function test1() {
        rec.onTokenReceived(a, u);
    }
    function test2() {
        address(rec).call(bytes4(sha3("onTokenReceived(address,uint256)")), a, u);
    }
    function test3() {
        Receiver(fallbackRec).onTokenReceived(a, u);
    } 
    function test4() {
        fallbackRec.call(bytes4(sha3("onTokenReceived(address,uint256)")), a, u);
    } 
    function test5() {
        Receiver(nonRec).onTokenReceived(a, u);
    }
    function test6() {
        nonRec.call(bytes4(sha3("onTokenReceived(address,uint256)")), a, u);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think I've got this figured out.

For one thing, from another answer: "Please note the difference: _target.call(..) returns false if call was not successful, while cm.registrationRequest(..) throws an exception."

[Interaction between two smart contracts - 'call' function fails. Why?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11283/interaction-between-two-smart-contracts-call-function-fails-why?rq=1)

Presumably this is because Solidity compiles the static call with code that throws if `false` is returned.

Also, it turns out that if there's an empty fallback function defined, it returns true by default, but if there's no such fallback it returns false. Test code:

```
contract F {
    function () {}
}

contract N {}

contract Test {
    event Log(bool x);
    function TestF() {
        address f = address(new F());
        Log(f.call());
    }
    function TestN() {
        address n = address(new N());
        Log(n.call());
    }
}
```

I.e. it must be that fallbacks return `false` by default but when Solidity compiles `F` it actually compiles the fallback to `function () { return true; }`...which is consistent with how functions generally work in Solidity.