# Difference between STOP and INVALID opcode

Tags: evm, invalid-opcode, revert-opcode

STOP halts execution and according to [this](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/141) mentions INVALID is used as an abort. Is the difference between these opcodes purely semantical?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`STOP` is a valid stop to the contract.  State changes are kept and unsued gas is refunded.

`INVALID` will throw the transaction, its state changes and cause the consumption of all gas sent with it.

As of Solidity 0.4.10 there is now a `revert()` call which enacts the `REVERT` opcode introduced in [EIP140](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/140). This opcode, halts the contract, throws state changes but refunds unused gas.