# How to trigger contract fallback function from Javascript

Tags: contract-development, web3js, fallback-function

For a simple contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract Test {
   uint private val;

   function getVal() constant returns(uint) {
       return val;
   }

   function setVal(uint newVal) payable {
       val = newVal;
   }

   function() {
       val++;
   }
}
```

`getVal` will be called from web3.js something like this:

```
contract.getVal.call(function(err, val) {
    //
});
```

`setVal` will be called from web3.js something like this:

```
contract.setVal.sendTransaction(newVal, 
  {
     gas: gas, 
     from: web3.eth.defaultAccount
  }, 
  function(err, result) {
      //
  });
```

How to trigger unnamed function from Javascript? Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest is to use [web3.eth.sendTransaction](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction).

Use the contract address for `to`.  Leave `data` empty (this is the field that determines which function is invoked in a contract).  Usually you would specify the amount of wei `value`, but you can omit this if you just want to invoke the fallback function.

Fallback functions are not intended to be used the way you might be planning.  For example: they are not executed after any other function executes (you can't do work in other functions and expect that the fallback would be called to then increment a variable); they are also not intended for cleanup.

For more background: [When does the fallback function get called?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12106/when-does-the-fallback-function-get-called)

Answer (score 0):

To call a contract fallback function you can use the below way using Javascript:

Consider I have to call a set function that has a uint256 as a parameter.

```
        const demo = await Demo.new();
        const valueToUpdate = 1234;
        const signature = web3.utils.sha3('set(uint256)').slice(0,10);
        const msgData = signature + web3.utils.toHex(valueToUpdate).slice(2).padStart(64, '0');
        await web3.eth.sendTransaction({
            from: yourAddress,
            to: demo.address,
            // value: ???,     // If you want to send ether with the call.
            // gas: ???,       // If you want to specify the gas.
            // gasPrice: ???,  // If you want to specify the gas price.
            data: msgData},
        );
```