# Sending ether via Contract instance

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation

My contract instance is created like:

```
var instance = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(addressA);
```

instance.sendTransaction is showing error in this case, what's the correct way to send ether to this contract?

Comment: "is showing error" Maybe knowing the actual error would help.

Comment: 'instance.sendTransaction is not a function'

Comment: I think you're looking for `web3.eth.sendTransaction`.

Comment: related https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16616/how-to-trigger-contract-fallback-function-from-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`web3.eth.sendTransaction()`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction) and set the contract's address in the "to" field of your transaction object.

Here is how to send a transaction :

```
var abi=[//your abi array];
var contractAddress = "//your contract address";
var contract = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(contractAddress);
```

//if you have the fallback payable :

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({from:web3.eth.accounts[X],to:contractAddress , value:web3.utils.toWei('0.0000001','ether')}) //the value is an example
```

// if you have a specific payable function

```
 contract.functionName.sendTransaction(parameter_1,parameter_2,parameter_n,{{from:web3.eth.accounts[X], value:xyz}},function (error, result){   if(!error){
                        console.log(result);
                    } else{
                        console.log(error);
                    }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

The contract can not send ether unless you write a function that does it. `sendTransaction` is not a function of your contract that is why you get the error: "instance.sendTransaction is not a function". You either send a normal transaction as smarx wrote in the comments or If you need the ether to come from a contract that does something in your application, you can add this function:

```
function resendEther(address recipient) public payable{
    recipient.transfer(msg.value);
}
```

Then you can use the instance:

```
instance = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(addressA);
instance.resendEther('recipientaddress', {value: 'etheramount'});
```

Hope this helps.