# fallback function, best practices when registering information

Tags: contract-development, fallback-function

I'm currently working on a smart-contract, and I have this warning in Remix :

```
Fallback function of contract browser/token.sol requires too much gas 
(102480).
If the fallback function requires more than 2300 gas, the contract 
cannot receive Ether.
```

I understand that, when executing the fallback method, I'm in a context of limited available gas. But for a token creation, for instance, I need to write multiple variables to have an accurate accounting of my token distribution.

```
function() payable {
  require(block.number > icoStartBlock && block.number < icoEndBlock);

  uint256 tokenAmount = msg.value * ((block.number < icoPremiumEndBlock) ? 550 : 500);

  shares[msg.sender] += msg.value;
  balances[msg.sender] += tokenAmount;
  balances[owner] += tokenAmount / 6;

  raised += msg.value;
  created += tokenAmount;
}
```

If the user that send Ether to my smart-contract know there is a need for more gas, will it be working if he sends more ? Am I doing an anti-pattern ? The `the contract cannot receive Ether` part of the message on Remix is scaring me a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning `the contract cannot receive Ether` is in the context of another contract sending your contract ether.

Your contract, let's call it `C` cannot receive ether from another contract `D` that uses Solidity's `send` function.

One way to avoid the warnings is to give the function in `C` a name, like `buy`:

`function buy() payable { ... }`

`D` can then send ether using `instanceOfC.buy.value(etherAmountInWei)()`.

Here is an example of `C` getting paid by `D`:

```
contract C {
    function getBalance() constant returns(uint) {
        return this.balance;
    }

    function buy() payable public {
        // logic
    }

}

contract D {
    // allows D to be funded with some ether during its creation
    function D() payable {
    }

    function getBalance() constant returns(uint) {
        return this.balance;
    }

    function sendToC(address c) public {
        C(c).buy.value(12)();
    }
}
```

For non-contracts that want to send ether to `C`, they now have to call `buy` instead of "just sending ether" (via the fallback function).  A user already has to increase their transaction's gas limit from 21,000 and they would now also have to pass the Method ID of `buy`.

For other guidance see [When does the fallback function get called?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12106/when-does-the-fallback-function-get-called) including

> Since fallback functions can be misused or abused, Vitalik Buterin
>   [suggested](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/47ts9p/is_it_unsafe_to_send_eth_from_contracts_with_the/d0fperf)
>   "establishing as a convention that fallback functions should generally
>   not be used except in very specific cases."