# Can i write in the data field of a transaction?

Tags: ropsten, sendtransaction

I read here [Is it possible to insert some custom data in the DATA field of an Ethereum Transaction?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/73622/is-it-possible-to-insert-some-custom-data-in-the-data-field-of-an-ethereum-trans) that it is not possible to write in the data field of a transaction, even if it is a simple balance transfer.
But I was able send a transaction (with ethers io library with the method sendtransaction) after overidding the tx data field with data 0xcAdd..,
The transaction was send to Ropsten and it was mined and confirmed in a block and the data were shown in the dtaa field . 
How is this possible? Can we write in data field whatever we want by overidding the tx before sending it to blockchain?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can but you should be aware of some things.

A [simple ether balance transfer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/how-does-a-solidity-fallback-function-work-with-the-raw-call-opcode-of-the-evm) will [still run some contract code](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1585/why-does-an-empty-message-still-invoke-the-code-of-the-contract).

Because code runs, there are ways a user can be tricked to run code that harms the user: for example, a user could be [tricked to lose their tokens.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29717/is-sending-some-datas-in-the-data-field-safe).