# Where can I learn to read a flow of opcodes and learn how to debug transactions?

Tags: solidity, gas, evm, opcode, optimization

There are many [tools](https://etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0x006f38dfa839cdb0f3fcfd77dbeb50c1d9b183f5e1c81c31e6d2db3a4d27b5e9) and [visualizers](https://etherscan.io/visualizer?tx=0x006f38dfa839cdb0f3fcfd77dbeb50c1d9b183f5e1c81c31e6d2db3a4d27b5e9&type=txn) to use to read through a transaction, but where can I go to learn how to understand this?

Fore example, that first link has a series of opcodes (and their associated gas and depth). If I had access to the contract, would I be able to compare the opcodes to different parts of the contract? Do solidity functions match up with opcode(s)? In order to read this, must I see a group of say 5 opcodes and know "oh this is adding two numbers"?

Comment: Check out [ethervm.io](https://ethervm.io/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in Ethereum is executed on the Ethereum Virtual Machine which is a stack-machine which executes instructions. A call to any contract starts with the instruction pointer at 0 meaning that the first instruction in the code placed on an address is always executed first.

A short introduction to how function calls are handled in Ethereum, on an opcode level, can be found in this answer: [What is the program counter at the start of an Ethereum method execution?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12797/what-is-the-program-counter-at-the-start-of-an-ethereum-method-execution)

It is definitely possible to learn what the different opcodes mean. It is certainly easier if you have some prior knowledge of machine code or assembly code but that is by no means a requirement (you have to start somewhere, right? And EVM is no more complicated that most RISC architectures).

The best source on this is to my knowledge the [Ethereum Yellow Paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) Appendix H which lists all the available opcodes for the Ethereum Virtual Machine.

For example the opcode `ADD` (0x01) (page 28 of the Yellow Paper) removes two values from the stack and adds one new value to the stack where the new value on top of the stack will be the sum of the two values removed from the stack (modulus 2^256).

Comment: "removes to values from the stack"? Perhaps you meant "two"?