# Decode input parameter without ABI

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, abi, decoding

I have a transaction with input data that looks like this:

```
0x2293db5700000000000000000000000030823e060e8be429b34bd9192df9cad4b166a056
```

I know that the last 40 characters is the token address which translates to

```
0x + 8051325147ec6df28f8f8b7fa4248e84c5a2e486
```

Is there any way to decode such input data? Do solidity contracts use some default encoding for input parameters?

Comment: when u send a transaction to a contract to call a function, the function knows what is coming in (type of the data) and that is why It can decode it

Comment: @MajdTL I know that it's going to be an address type. I want to basically repeat what contract is doing and decode it the way contract would decode it.

Comment: Take look at this , they do something similar https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11144/how-to-decode-input-data-from-a-transaction

Comment: @MajdTL this is not what I need as I don't have an ABI for this specific contract. I know that last 40 characters of this input data is of type address, therefore I want to find out how does Solidity contract decode this into actual address?

Comment: https://medium.com/mycrypto/why-do-we-need-transaction-data-39c922930e92 maybe this will help understand how solidity do it. What I can say is: the contract knows which function it should be called using the id of that function (2293db57) and that function knows the data type of its Parameter so it knows how long it is and at which position it starts and end.

Comment: @Marijus Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange! You want to find out how does Solidity contract decode this into actual address... So do you want an answer that takes a specific contract and shows which EVM bytecode is related to decoding? Here is a conceptual starting point in case it helps: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7602/how-does-the-evm-find-the-entry-of-a-called-function  Maybe this article someone wrote too: https://medium.com/@hayeah/how-to-decipher-a-smart-contract-method-call-8ee980311603

Comment: Have you tried decompiling the contract in etherscan?

Comment: @pguardiario why would I need to decompile the contract?

Comment: @Marijus to get the source code / abi

Comment: @pguardiario the contract is not verified therefore I am not able to get code / abi, however, I don't really need it because I can clearly see that it's a proxy function that calls pancakeswap. And the only input there is an address which is what I need. The problem is that it's encoded in some weird way and it's not enough to take the last 40 characters of the data. Take a look at this tx: https://bscscan.com/tx/0x795738c36176beb1fec0b5b1dc101b5f7d424c6450005212ff45aa5a63a24047

Comment: @Marijus please see my answer below and hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Solidity is a typed language, so it's aware of the types of function parameters. When you call a certain function on a contract, Solidity knows that the type of the first parameter is an address, and can decode it as such. ABI is automatically generated from the types specified in the Solidity source code.

For a simple case of just getting an address from this particular input data, you can just do something like this (in JS):

```js
const input = '0x2293db5700000000000000000000000030823e060e8be429b34bd9192df9cad4b166a056';
const address = `0x${input.slice(-40)}`;

console.log(address); // 0x30823e060e8be429b34bd9192df9cad4b166a056
```

In other cases where you may want to decode other types of data, you can first slice of the first 4 bytes (8 hexadecimal characters), and use something like Ethers.js' ABI decoder:

```js
import { defaultAbiCoder } from '@ethersproject/abi';

const input = '0x2293db5700000000000000000000000030823e060e8be429b34bd9192df9cad4b166a056';
const address = defaultAbiCoder.decode(['address'], input.slice(10));

console.log(address); // 0x30823e060e8be429b34bd9192df9cad4b166a056
```

You can replace `address` with the type of the parameter, and if your contract function has multiple input parameters, simply add them to the array.

Comment: The problem here is that the actual address is '0x8051325147ec6df28f8f8b7fa4248e84c5a2e486' since the contract for this function is not verified.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. The input data you provided contains the address `0x30823e060e8be429b34bd9192df9cad4b166a056`, not `0x8051325147ec6df28f8f8b7fa4248e84c5a2e486`.

Comment: Take a look at this tx: https://bscscan.com/tx/0x795738c36176beb1fec0b5b1dc101b5f7d424c6450005212ff45aa5a63a24047

Input says it's 0x551eb7e6272297b4feee7e96c8ce343ba4282863 but the real token is actually 0xe5cdbbb16e451e6fc22a2cf04113706bd0ec6cb3

Answer (score 0):

If you go here:
https://bscscan.com/address/0x890308ccaeb490a536ee70230f9183524b17f082#code
You'll see a button to decompile the contract:
[image]

It seems like you can work out the abi from the result:
[image]