# Function with 3 return values returning zeros, but was working fine for 2 return values

Tags: contract-development

I have this sample contract that I am trying to run. The function getvalues returns me correct values set earlier, when the setvalues function was written to set 2 values. when i modified the contract to set & return 3 values instead of 2, contract was mined successfully, but getvalues function returns only zeros.

Sample run:

```
sampcont2.setvalues(2500,100,120,130)
sampcont2.getvalues(2500)
```

output:

> [0,0,0]

When the contract was written to set and return 2 values:

```
sampcont2.setvalues(2500,100,120)
sampcont2.getvalues(2500)
```

output:

> [100,120]

Here is the contract that returns 3 values:

```
contract sampcont2{

    struct customer{
        uint custid;
        uint custvalue1;
        uint custvalue2;
        uint custvalue3;
        string comments;

    }

    mapping(uint => customer) customers;

      function setvalues(uint cid,uint a,uint b,uint c) {
        customers[cid].custid = cid;
        customers[cid].custvalue1 = a;
        customers[cid].custvalue2 = b;
        customers[cid].custvalue3 = c;

    }


    function getvalues(uint id) constant returns (uint x,uint y,uint z) {

         return (customers[id].custvalue1,customers[id].custvalue2,
         customers[id].custvalue3);
    }                
}
```

Edit:
This is what I see:

> I0922 13:49:51.737177 core/database_util.go:353] stored block receipts [01f78178.]
>   I0922 13:49:51.737177 core/tx_pool.go:547] removed tx (
>          TX(c56cb49dcfd4828ea4bc7dd903de834b4119dbf6d368d9015df423dff11d82f4)
>          Contract: false
>          From:     85e148c97b24c1c1a3bfe91782cb2c9831c38b98
>          To:       4d37aa6cc5c73464265faefe668d5beb8f517edd
>          Nonce:    248
>          GasPrice: 20000000000
>          GasLimit  90000
>          Value:    0
>          Data:     >0x4378d76f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003ec00000>00000000000000000000000000000000000000
>   0000000000000000000660000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000>00010e00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>   0000000000010e
>          V:        0x1b
>          R:        >0xb52e254bb50c4c244124b9ac96b215b0d3265bd5bb676b22a8c081801c715037
>          S:        >0x42889e66fcdcb0734dc78f081b598b0a3b467cf3e13d14cfa832035a19309163
>          Hex:      >f8eb81f88504a817c80083015f90944d37aa6cc5c73464265faefe668d5beb8f517edd80b884437>8d76f000000000000000000000000000000000
>   00000000000000000000000000003ec000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000>00000000000000660000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>   00000000000000000000010e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000>00000010e1ba0b52e254bb50c4c244124b9ac96b215b0d3265bd5bb6
>   76b22a8c081801c715037a042889e66fcdcb0734dc78f081b598b0a3b467cf3e13d14cfa832035a>19309163
>   ) from pool: low tx nonce or out of funds

So is it actually a gas problem?

Comment: I suggest trying with more gas.

Comment: thx , I will try that, but I am already using 4700000 in the contract, while the transaction and execution costs are as below:   Transaction cost: 172257 gas. 
Execution cost: 92317 gas.

Comment: I am using Broswer-solidity, i tried copying the text within Web3 deploy box, increased the gas amount there which was previously set to 4700000. however, anything greater than 4700000 throws an error : "Exceeds Block Gas Limit undefined"

Comment: Can you confirm that your contract was deployed with `eth.getCode(addressOfContract)`?

Comment: Yes Xavier, it did. I got the Bytecode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated 11:53 Sep 22 2016**

Yes it is a gas problem. Your `setvalues(2500,100,120,130)` transaction was sent with the default gas of 90,000. This transaction requires at least 102,768 gas.

#### Details Below

I'm testing out using the latest Solidity realtime compiler and `geth` 1.4.11-stable in local dev mode with the following command:

```
geth --datadir ~/EtherDev/data --dev --nodiscover --mine --minerthreads 1 --port 30301 --maxpeers 0 --verbosity 3 --unlock 0 --password ~/EtherDev/etc/passwordfile --rpc --rpccorsdomain '*' console
```

I deployed your contract as shown in the following screen:

[image]

I called `setvalues(2500,100,120,130)` as shown in the following screen:

[image]

You can see that 102,768 gas was used in sending the transaction.

And I queried `getvalues(2500)` as shown in the following screen:

[image]

Comment: I was hoping upgrading to latest geth would work, but looks like it doesn't help :(

Comment: thx @BokkyPooBah , so I tried changing gaslimit with --targetgaslimit as well, but on trying to setvalues, i still get gas limit as 90000, how can i get around this?

Comment: How are you deploying your contract, and how are you sending the transaction? Using `geth` command line?

Comment: Yes @BokkyPooBah

Comment: The syntax is like `c.stateChanger(3, {from:eth.accounts[0], gas: 400000})` from http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7557/syntax-for-calling-contract-state-changing-methods/7558#7558

Comment: thx many tons @BokkyPooBah... Finallllyyy solved this issue :) so do I always need to include this passing of extra gas with all my transactions? No simpler way that would apply to all transactions? I am asking this because its cumbersome to always calculate in advance and pass required amount of gas with each transaction.

Comment: Great. You will need to specify if you need more than the default 90,000 gas to transactions to execute contracts (21,000 for account to account transfers). Search this site for `estimateGas` to find out how to compute it. The link 2 comments above has some information on how you can trace your transaction's gas requirements.