# Calling a contract function in Geth console after mining the contract

Tags: contract-development, web3js, json-rpc

I got the message :
Contract mined! address: 0x72b878799d98131bca157ccaccfcd386023147e9 transactionHash: 0x66b9436240103e79c07492fe2479d97eeaa6c45779d00e1fc126285072eba327

for example, and there is a function named test() in the contract named foocontract.
how to call test() according to the contract address in geth console?

Comment: See http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8736/how-to-call-my-contracts-function-using-sendtransaction

Comment: @jeff please utilize close votes.