# web3.eth.call. How can I set "data" param?

Tags: contract-invocation

I deployed my first contract by using browser-solidity to make bytecode and `web3.eth.sendRawTransaction` to deploy.
The following is the transaction and the deployed contract code.

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x74426948905cd6e70e8b9d64a660b3c179b7c8a224ca5cd0234842768eb501db

**contract code**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract Addition {
  int num = 0;
  function add(int a){
    num += a;
  }
  function get() returns(int){
    return num;
  }
}
```

Then, I want to call the two methods by `web3.eth.call`. However, I can't find a way how to generate the "data" param. Could you please give me any advices?

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://xxx:xxx"));

const result = web3.eth.call({
    to: "0x692a70d2e424a56d2c6c27aa97d1a86395877b3a", 
    data: "???"
});
```

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcall

I think gas is needed to call but this example does not mention about it. On JavaScript VM on browser-solidity, the prices are showed when I execute the method like below.

```
Result: "0x"
Transaction cost: 41713 gas. 
Execution cost: 20249 gas.
```

---

Update 1

Seems this page describes about it.

> I then wanted to call the method "double" with the number "5". The Contract ABI documentation says that you have to take the first 4 bytes of the Keccak hash.
> The method signature is

> double(int)

> Which gives the hash with web3.sha3("double(int)":

> 6740d36c7d42fba12b8eb3b047193c9761224c267d7a2e96dc50949860652317

> The first four bytes, prefixed with "0x" are:

> 0x6740d36c

> The documentation then tells to take the parameter, encode it in hex and pad it left to 32 bytes. Which would be the following, using the number "5":

> 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005

> In total, the encoded string should look like this:

> 0x6740d36c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005

[How to call a contract method using the eth_call JSON-RPC API](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3514/how-to-call-a-contract-method-using-the-eth-call-json-rpc-api)

---

Update 2

It does not work.

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://xxx:xxx"));

var result = web3.eth.call({
    to: "0x692a70d2e424a56d2c6c27aa97d1a86395877b3a",
    data: "0x6d4ce63c" // var hash = web3.sha3("get()"); get first 4 byte
});

console.log(result); // 0x

var result = web3.eth.call({
    to: "0x692a70d2e424a56d2c6c27aa97d1a86395877b3a",
    data: "0x250fc6d90000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001" // var hash = web3.sha3("add(int)"); get first 4 byte and param (1)
});

console.log(result); // 0x

var result = web3.eth.call({
    to: "0x692a70d2e424a56d2c6c27aa97d1a86395877b3a",
    data: "0x6d4ce63c" // var hash = web3.sha3("get()"); get first 4 byte
});

console.log(result); // 0x => I expected 1
```

---

Updata 3

I changed from add(int) to add(int256) but still does not work.

```
var result = web3.eth.call({
    to: "0x692a70d2e424a56d2c6c27aa97d1a86395877b3a",
    data: "0x87db03b70000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001" // var hash = web3.sha3("add(int256)"); get first 4 byte and param (1)
});
```

However browser-solidity debugger shows the same data. So I think this data is correct.

---

Update 4

Seems I have to send transaction before call. I can imagine. I will try it.

> Call. It is a read-only operation and will not consume any Ether.

[What is the difference between a transaction and a call?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call)

---

Update 5

Although I think found the answer but still it does not work. I'll take a break..

**(1) sendRawTransaction**

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://xxxx:xxxx"));

const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');
const privateKey = new Buffer('xxxx', 'hex')

const rawTx = {
  nonce: '0x03',
  gasPrice: '0x53d9',
  gasLimit: '0x53d9',
  to: '0x692a70d2e424a56d2c6c27aa97d1a86395877b3a',
  data: '0x87db03b70000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001' // add(int256) with param 1
}

const tx = new Tx(rawTx);
tx.sign(privateKey);

const serializedTx = tx.serialize();

console.log('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex')); // 0xf885038253d98253d994692a70d2e424a56d2c6c27aa97d1a86395877b3a80a487db03b700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011ba0ec6de7c9c1f31dc95014156479925b2ebd933b715f2bb4450f5d74992d7b3423a016f6a7c6e1885412400a622f82ffa033936c06755896096c7638936c065571c1

web3.eth.sendRawTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'), function(err, hash) {
  if (!err) {
    console.log(hash); // 0x26db79c7c3c65992f17f4f62d5d191705933e785dff54db6d27e6f3a92d7117e
  } else {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x26db79c7c3c65992f17f4f62d5d191705933e785dff54db6d27e6f3a92d7117e

**(2) call get()**

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://xxxx:xxxx"));

const result = web3.eth.call({
    to: "0x692a70d2e424a56d2c6c27aa97d1a86395877b3a",
    data: "0x6d4ce63c"
});

console.log(result); // 0x => I expected 1
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to do this all by yourself. You can instead use `getData` method.

```
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI, contractAddress);
const callData = contract.functionName.getData(functionParameters);
const result = web3.eth.call({
    to: "0x692a70d2e424a56d2c6c27aa97d1a86395877b3a", 
    data: callData
});
```

web3.eth.call executes the call in VM of the node but this is not mined. This is kind of dry run.
If you instead want to send a transaction to blockchain use `web3.eth.sendTransaction`.

Comment: Thank you. I was feeling that is annoying. (hash and get 4bytes and add param...) I'll try to use it.

Comment: I will also check about web3.eth.sendTransaction

Comment: Sure. It's really annoying. I was also stuck in doing all this unnecessary stuff until I discovered getData.

Comment: I believe it's `const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI, contractAddress)` these days (web3 1.6.1)

Comment: by the way, the other parts seem to be different, too. I'm not sure if `getData` still exists; I've found that we can do `const call = universeContract.methods[methodName](callParameters)` (`callParameters` is the argument of `call` or an array containing that argument). However, I haven't found how to prepare a signed call yet and haven't called it actually

Comment: You can have a look at another question [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8736/how-to-call-my-contracts-function-using-sendtransaction/12932#12932) that has parts of getting data and sendng tx.

Answer (score 3):

Even I had to go through the same process until i discovered, the below:

use the web3.js library which helps in doing the same. Just download web3.js using NPM (or anywhere else) and get the modules required for the task, by:

```
const_ = require('lodash');
const SolidityFunction = require('web3/lib/web3/function');
```

You can use the web3.js library along with your ABI to find the function definition, using the below code:

```
var ABI = JSON.parse(<your_ABI>);
var functionDef = new SolidityFunction('', _.find(ABI, { name: '<your_function_name>' }), '');
```

After this, you can call the method toPayload which will help you converting the values that you want to pass to your function into HEX Data.

```
var payloadData = functionDef.toPayload([<value_for_var_1>, <value_for_var_2>, <value_for_var_3>, <value_for_var_4>]).data;
```

**payloadData** can be used as Value for the DATA property. Example:

```
var rawTx = {
 to: <to_address>,
 data: payloadData,
 value: '0x0',
 from: <from_address>,
 nonce: nonce,// You need to Get this using web3.eth.getTransactionCount
 gasLimit: gasLimit, // Get this by web3.eth.estimateGas
 gasPrice: gasPrice // use, web3.eth.gasPrice
}
```

You can use this approach and forget about how many zeros to pad with. As the **toPayload** function handles everything. You have a raw transaction object, you can use [ethereumjs-tx](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-tx) to sign your transaction and use [web3.eth.sendRawTransaction](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendrawtransaction) to call your Contract Function.

Hope this helps.