# execute function on ropsten tesnet thru geth, adapt truffle console/testrpc commands

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-invocation, testrpc-to-ropsten

This is the smart contract I'm trying to interact with, [verified on etherscan.io](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x8705c513da621a16fd1defc9de8ae7cdead01fb8#code), and reproduced here:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.13;

// This contract demonstrates a simple non-constant (transactional) function you can call from geth.
// increment() takes no parameters and merely increments the "iteration" value. 

contract Incrementer {
    uint iteration;

    function Incrementer() {
        iteration = 0;
    }

    function increment(uint count) {
        iteration += count;
    }

    function getIteration() constant returns (uint) {
        return iteration;
    }

}
```

The commands I'd like to use to call it are:

```
Incrementer.deployed().then(function(instance) {
  meta = instance;
  return meta.increment(1);
})
```

to increase the `iteration` variable, and:

```
Incrementer.deployed().then(function(instance) { 
    meta = instance; 
    return meta.getIteration(); 
})
```

to verify the result.

Those are commands that work on the `truffle console` with `testrpc`, but now I'm trying to issue those commands through `geth` to the `ropsten testnet`.

I've tried to adapt them to this purpose according to the answer to [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8736/how-to-call-my-contracts-function-using-sendtransaction), like so:

```
var contractAbi = eth.contract([{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"count","type":"uint256"}],"name":"increment","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getIteration","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"}]);
var myContract = contractAbi.at(0x8705C513da621a16fd1dEFc9dE8aE7CDEAD01Fb8);
var getData = myContract.getIteration.getData(1);
web3.eth.sendTransaction({to:0x8705C513da621a16fd1dEFc9dE8aE7CDEAD01Fb8, from:0xd7a9a61a480d458a1181e0563b07f944df4489a6, data: getData});
```

but it didn't work, the result was this:

```
Error: invalid address
    at web3.js:3879:15
    at web3.js:3705:20
    at web3.js:4948:28
    at map (<native code>)
    at web3.js:4947:12
    at web3.js:4973:18
    at web3.js:4998:23
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

The output of `getData` rendered in this way:

```
> getData

"0xfc2c3e08"
```

See the console output here:

[image]

What is the correct procedure to adapt those commands to execute a function on the `ropsten tesnet` using `geth console`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to work if you put the addresses in quotes:

```
> var contractAbi = eth.contract([{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"count","type":"uint256"}],"name":"increment","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getIteration","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"}]);

undefined

> var myContract = contractAbi.at("0x8705C513da621a16fd1dEFc9dE8aE7CDEAD01Fb8");

undefined

> var getData = myContract.getIteration.getData(1);

undefined

> personal.unlockAccount(eth.coinbase, 'hunter2')

true

web3.eth.sendTransaction({to:"0x8705C513da621a16fd1dEFc9dE8aE7CDEAD01Fb8", from:"0xd7a9a61a480d458a1181e0563b07f944df4489a6", data: getData});

"0xb8d229d46500681f08ae7286359dc052036d14e2814bbf9bca6ea217b904345b"
```

and so I guess the result of the transaction is [here on etherscan.io](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xb8d229d46500681f08ae7286359dc052036d14e2814bbf9bca6ea217b904345b):

[image]

It says that I called the function `getIteration()`, and it's true, I did do that.

**BUT**

*be forewarned, this is not immediately relevant to the question in the OP...*

dig this strange situation:

when I [call the increment function](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x451de0f5f9615f3fa9407a58328a21a7ac34ba0046e88d24d1ccb05b22a45f44) with a value of `1`, i.e.:

```
var getData = myContract.increment.getData(1);
```

[I get this](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xd68358bfe87aaf685bc6f61689e0da0c51166e28e6415813bf4e59d9e7a27d05):

```
Function: increment(uint256 count)

MethodID: 0x7cf5dab0
[0]:0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

ok, fair enough- the rub is- when I call it with `666`, I get:

```
Function: increment(uint256 count)

MethodID: 0x7cf5dab0
[0]:000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000029a
```

when I would have expected `667`.

What is that result? some kind of strange hex encoding?

Comment: yeah so, `29a` is exactly `666` in hex representation, you can check it here: 

http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter