# How to use web3 to send money from wallet A to wallet B?

Tags: web3js, transactions, blockchain, wallets

```
var myContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);
var address = contract address;
var contract_data = myContract.at(address);
var sender = '0xd3aaa525c087978133abb517593ea334f16abd1f';
var receiver = '0xff2b56315dc5372b45dfa3773c4cfd64f70c8e9c';
//transfer is the function in the contract to transfer money from wallet A to B
var getData = contract_data.transfer.getData(receiver,amount);
web3.eth.sendTransaction({to:receiver, from:sender, data: getData});
```

Source: [How to call my contract's function using sendTransaction](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8736/how-to-call-my-contracts-function-using-sendtransaction)

When I am tracking the balance, it turns out that only gas price is being
deducted from wallet A and nothing else ? But when I use metamask UI to do the
transactions, balances are updated successfully. I believe, there is some 
flaw with the way I am using this api, it'd be really great if anyone could 
share their experience.

Comment: Did you try debugging the transaction? Did the transaction ran out of gas? What network are you using, main-net, Ropsten?

Comment: I was justing using the local network for testing using "testrpc" on localhost.

Comment: Just check if the transaction is not consuming all gas. Check this post for details: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6007/how-can-the-transaction-status-from-a-thrown-error-be-detected-when-gas-can-be-e

Answer (score 10):

You need to pass `value` in Wei form to `sendTransaction` method:

```
web3.sendTransaction({to:receiver, from:sender, value:web3.toWei("0.5", "ether")})
```

`sender` account should be unlocked for this to succeed.

[source](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction)

---

to send tokens you need to call

```
contract_data.transfer(receiver,amount{from:web3.eth.accounts[0]});
```

or something among those lines. You don't need to use `web3.eth.sendTransaction`

Comment: `value` is used to send ethers. But I guess OP is asking for transferring tokens (maybe erc-20).

Comment: I'm guessing he wants to send ethers because he is wondering why only gas is deducted

Comment: Hey, Thanks a lot. Yes, I intend to transfer tokens. And I need to use the transfer function of my contract to do that.

Comment: I updated my solution to send tokens

Comment: You're missing web3.eth.sendTransaction

Answer (score 0):

```
//set web3 variable
const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);

//get all the accounts
const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

//if you're using react
this.setState({web3, accounts});

//send the tx using react
this.state.web3.eth.sendTransaction({to: contractAddress, from: this.state.accounts[0], value: ETHamount});
```

or if you're not using react

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({to: address, from: address, value: inWei});
```

A conversion of wei to eth can be found [here](https://eth-converter.com/). Information on web3 variable setting (it uses [infura](https://infura.io/) usually as the endpoint [aka the provider]) can be found [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **web3.js 1.3.x**, this is what worked in my case:

```
web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei(amount, 'ether'))
```

For whichever reason, the below command was sending a wrong value into Metamask.

```
web3.utils.toWei(amount, 'ether')
```

Answer (score 0):

With metamask:

```
window.ethereum.request({
  method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
  params: [{
    to,
    from,
    value: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei("0.5")),
  }],
})
.then(() => {
  alert("Woot!")
})
.catch((e) => {
  alert("Oops!")
})
```