# how to set msg.value in metamask?

Tags: web3js, metamask, ethereum-wallet-dapp, dapp-development

I am using MetaMask chrome extension, for my Dapp. I have a function which needs to transfer some amount to another account. This amount is of the order 200 to 800 wei. How do I set msg.value() attribute in MetaMask popup window?

This feature can be seen on remix, but I could not find it on MetaMask?

Comment: Might be duplicate of https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/32965/852

Answer (score 3):

Worked for me:

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
  to:'0xf17f52151EbEF6C7334FAD080c5704D77216b732', 
  from:'0xf17f52151EbEF6C7334FAD080c5704D77216b732', 
  value:web3.toWei("0.5", "ether")
}, console.log)
```

[image]