# How to call contract functions using web3?

Tags: web3js, nodejs

I have deployed my contract in private blockchain, now I am calling functions using Nodejs and web3. 
Here, I want to transfer tokens for which I need to unlock my account from which I am transferring the tokens and then I want to check the balance of the account to which the tokens were transfered.
Here, is the code:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(new 
Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
var Personal = require('web3-eth-personal')
var personal = new Personal(Personal.givenProvider)

var ABI = {contract abi}
web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount("0xcc8d743....97278fe497ee90...", "password", 
60).then(
contract.methods.transfer('0x43a91c052B913299Dd4F47C91bB7d982D8A8632e', 
2).send({from:'0xCc8d743eB486bF38ED1197278Fe497eE90...', gas:210000})
.on("result", 
contract.methods.balanceOf('0x43a91c052B913299Dd4F47C91bB7d982D8A8632e')
.call((error, result)=>console.log(result))).on("error", function(error) 
{console.log(error);}))
```

But I am getting the balance of the account first which should be called after transfer function and for the transfer function I am getting the error saying 'need authentication'.

```
100000008
Error: Returned error: authentication needed: password or unlock
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code. It's all mentioned clearly in documentation, [unlocking account](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-personal.html#unlockaccount) and [send transaction](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id23). You can also see [how-to-call-my-contracts-function-using-sendtransaction](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8736/how-to-call-my-contracts-function-using-sendtransaction)

```
let isUnlocked = await web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount("0xcc8d743....97278fe497ee90...", "password", 
60)

if(isUnlocked){
  myContract.methods.myMethod(123).send({from: '0xcc8d743....97278fe497ee90...'}, (error, txHash) => {
    // handle the error here
    if(!err && txHash){
      myContract..methods.balanceOf('0xcc8d743....97278fe497ee90...', (err, balance) => {
        console.log('balance is', balance)
      })
    }
});

}
```

Using Callbacks

```
web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount('0x..', 'password', (unlocked) => {
  myContract.methods.myMethod(123).send({from: '0xcc8d743....97278fe497ee90...'}, (error, txHash) => {
    if(!err && txHash){
      myContract..methods.balanceOf('0xcc8d743....97278fe497ee90...', (err, balance) => {
        console.log('balance is', balance)
      })
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: If I use await I have to use async also. I don't know how to use async and await @Prashant Prabhakar Singh

Comment: @cryptoS. It's no big deal. Still, if you don't want to use async-await. use callbacks for unlocking too.