# Why can't I connect by IPC?

Tags: nodejs, ipc

I have successfully run `geth --rpc` to test some functionality, but I need the `personal` API which [according to this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/how-can-i-make-new-account-by-json-rpc) should be done by IPC.

When I run

```
geth --ipcapi "db,eth,net,web3,personal" --ipcpath /tmp/geth.ipc
```

This creates the ipc file and geth appears to otherwise start normally.

I have the following npm modules installed: `web3` `web3_extended` `web3_ipc`

Then I run this on nodejs:

```
var web3_extended = require('web3_extended');

var options =
{
    host:     '/tmp/geth.ipc',
    ipc:      true,
    personal: true, 
    admin:    false,
    debug:    false
};

var web3 = web3_extended .create (options);

var coinbase = web3.eth.coinbase;
```

The last line gives me an HTML response which includes

```
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

and

```
Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

That Apache line makes me think nodejs isn't even attempting to connect by IPC.

Why not? Or, what else is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Summary

Q: Why can't I connect by IPC? Why not? Or, what else is the problem?

A: From your HTML response message, it seems like your code is currently using the version of web3_extended that does not support the IPC protocol.

---

## Details

Can you check that you are using [tjade273/web3_extended](https://github.com/tjade273/web3_extended/blob/master/index.js) and NOT [The18thWarrior/web3_extended](https://github.com/The18thWarrior/web3_extended/blob/master/index.js)?

The first was forked from the second, and includes the IPC protocol handling. From [tjade273/web3_extended/blob/index.js - lines 7 to 15](https://github.com/tjade273/web3_extended/blob/master/index.js#L7-L15):

```
function create(options) {
    if(options.ipc){
        var client = new net.Socket();
        web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.IpcProvider(options.host,client));
    }
    else{
        web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider(options.host));
    }
    if (options.personal) {
```

while the original code from [The18thWarrior/web3_extended/blob/index.js - lines 6 to 9](https://github.com/The18thWarrior/web3_extended/blob/master/index.js#L6-L9):

```
function create(options) {
    web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider(options.host));

    if (options.personal) {
```

Comment: Thanks! That looks like the reason. Aside from pulling files down manually, is there a way I can set up npm/ubuntu to obtain the right version?

Comment: @spraff You can use `npm install web3_ipc` to install mine as opposed to `web3_extended` for the other version

Comment: I also have same issue, but i didn't get the proper solution. Do i need to install only `web3_ipc` and not `web3_extended`? As in this case I am getting error `cannot find node module web3_extended`. And If install both node modules `web3_extended` and `web3_ipc` , I get same error as `Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.` Please help!