# Connect to node via IPC

Tags: web3js, ipc, connections

As per my knowledge, RPC  connection to a node is quite unsafe. so the alternative is connecting to a node via IPC. But how to connect to node via IPC? 
I have used web3 for connecting to node via RPC and interact with my ethereum application. Can I use web3 for connection via IPC also or there is some other library that I need to explore. TIA
**Edit:** 
I have tried using both web3_extended and web3_ipc.

When I install `web3_ipc` inside my node project and use
 `var web3_extended = require('web3_extended')`,
 I get error `Cannot find node module 1web3_extended`.

When I install either `web3_extended` or both `web3_extended` and `web3_ipc` , then at run time I get error like

```
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br>
```

I think only installation of web3_ipc will be sufficient but as per documentation I have to use require('web3_extended') in both cases. Can anybody point at what I am missing?

Comment: Related http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/how-can-i-make-new-account-by-json-rpc and http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3393/why-cant-i-connect-by-ipc

Comment: Try https://github.com/tjade273/web3_ipc

Comment: Thanks for pointing out toward web3_ipc. But do I need to have knowldege of node.js for using web3_extended? I tried to use web3 but on using `var web3_extended = require('web3_extended');` . I get require not defined error. Any help?