# Is it possible to call debug_traceTransaction from nodejs?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, json-rpc, nodejs

Following answer (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/9437/4575)  [ 1 ] guide us to call `debug_trace` through using `geth`:

> As documented in [debug.traceTransaction(...)](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#debug_tracetransaction), you can only access this API call using the geth JavaScript console or the JSON-RPC API. There
>   is no web3 API that I know of. There are some unofficial extension
>   web3 APIs, but I don't know if debug.traceTransaction is supported by
>   these. Looks like you have to use JSON-RPC to access this data.

but I was wondering is it possible to call `debug_Transaction` inside `nodejs` ?

I tried the steps on https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/9462/4575 [ 2 ] but it seems does not work for me and this answer seems contradict with the previous answer I have lined on [ 1 ].

```
var web3 = new Web3();
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));

web3.currentProvider.sendAsync({
        method: "debug_traceTransaction",
        params: ['<transaction_id>', {}],
        jsonrpc: "2.0",
        id: "2"
    }, function (err, result) {
        console.log( result );
    });
```

Output result:

```
{ jsonrpc: '2.0',
  id: '2',
  error:
   { code: -32601,
     message: 'The method debug_traceTransaction does not exist/is not available' } }
```

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(Here is the same response as the one I added to the question referenced above)

If I start `geth` using the following command line:

```
Iota:~ user$ geth --rpc console
```

And I try to execute the following `curl` command:

```
Iota:~ user$ curl localhost:8545 -X POST --header 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0", "method":"debug_traceTransaction", "params":["0x3684f071b34da1116282ee88a106a8f2a266d273ef7d8964957f65128fb58d77", {}], "id":1}'
```

I get the following result:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"error":{"code":-32601,"message":"The method debug_traceTransaction does not exist/is not available"}}
```

If instead I start `geth` with the following command:

```
Iota:~ user$  geth --rpc --rpcapi "eth,net,web3,debug" console
```

And I run the same `curl` command, I get the transaction trace as shown below:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":{"gas":45480,"returnValue":"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001","structLogs":[{"pc":0,"op":"PUSH1","gas":76741,"gasCost":3,"depth":1,"error":null,"stack":[],"memory":null,"storage":{}},{"pc":2,"op":"PUSH1","gas":76738,"gasCost":3,"depth":1,"error":null,"stack":["0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060"],"memory":null,"storage":{}},{ ...
```

Also note that you cannot get the `debug_traceTransaction` information from the section of the blockchain that you have `--fast` synced.

So, you just need to add the `--rpcapi "eth,net,web3,debug"` command line option.

---

### Update Responding To Comment Below

@Avatar, please check out https://github.com/tjade273/web3_ipc/blob/master/index.js#L328-L335 . See also [Why can't I connect by IPC?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3393/why-cant-i-connect-by-ipc) and [Connect to node via IPC](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10651/connect-to-node-via-ipc) as these use the same library.

Comment: I do approve your answer and it works through using `geth`, and I appreciated your answer. My question is about (I just wanted to double check) , does your answer means that am I require to use `geth` since it is not possible to call `debug_traceTransaction` through `nodejs` or other applications? The reason I need to call `debug_traceTransaction` is related to your answer to check transaction status. [http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/6011/4575]

Comment: From your nodejs result, which matches my JSON-RPC result when I don't have the `--rpcapi ...debug` option, it seems that your nodejs call to `debug_traceTransaction` is getting to `geth` via JSON-RPC but `geth` is returning the message that the `debug_traceTransaction` call is unavailable. So theoretically you should be able to access `debug_traceTransaction` via nodejs. Am I missing something else?

Comment: Just as note, on the background `geth` works as you recommended and it works that `geth` returns me the `debug_traceTransaction` information. So the issue might be related to the way I am calling `debug_traceTransaction` inside `nodejs`, where `nodejs` unable to find/call `debug_traceTransaction` function.

Comment: Updated answer with web3_ipc which includes the call to `debug_traceTransaction`.

Comment: I have tried to example related to Example of RPC Connection on https://github.com/tjade273/web3_ipc/blob/master/README.md: I am facing with `Error: The method admin_datadir does not exist/is not available.`

Comment: Have you added `admin` to the `--rpcapi` option?