# Could we run `Parity` where we could have access to web3.debug on javaScript console?

Tags: web3js, parity, console

`Parity` does not return anything for `web3.debug` on java script console.

The way I run `Parity`:

```
parity --chain parity.json --network-id 23422 --reserved-peers myPrivateNetwork.txt --jsonrpc-apis web3,eth,net,parity,parity_accounts,traces,rpc,parity_set,personal-ludp=debug,tcp=debug,sync=debug --author "0x75a4c787c5c18c587b284a904165ff06a269b48c"
```

When I run `--jsonrpc-apis` with `debug` it gives following error:

```
Unknown api: debug
```

[Q] Could we run `Parity` where we could have access to web3.debug?

This works for when I use `geth`. For `geth` based on following [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/10756/4575) I have followed: https://github.com/tjade273/web3_ipc/blob/master/README.md