# remix: The method debug_traceTransaction does not exist/is not available

Tags: remix, contract-debugging

I have followed this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/10756/4575).

> So, you just need to add the `--rpcapi "eth,net,web3,debug"` command
>   line option.

The way I run my geth:

```
geth --datadir /home/user/POA/private --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpc --rpcport
8545 --rpccorsdomain="*" --networkid 32224 --rpcapi eth,net,web3,personal,debug
--port 3000
```

---

But on `remix` or `remix-alpha` when I try to debug the function call I have face with the following error: `The method debug_traceTransaction does not exist/is not available`.

[image]

**[Q]** How could I fix this error? What might be the reason of this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to open `txpool` rpc api.

Can you add  `--rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal,txpool,miner"`?

It can help.