# What is the correct geth ipc path usage from nodejs console?

Tags: go-ethereum, nodejs

I cant connect my nodejs console to my geth node via ipc. I'm doing something wrong but cant figure it out. Also I cant find my ipc files anywhere.

Using geth v1.6.6

I start my private network default geth node and see the IPC path as below.

```
INFO [08-18|10:01:49] IPC endpoint opened: \\.\pipe\geth.ipc
```

this is from another node. The path to the ipc doesn't even exist. Do I have to create it manually?

```
INFO [08-18|10:13:41] IPC endpoint opened: \\.\pipe\C:\Users\myuser/Library/Ethereum/mynode1/geth.ipc
```

I start the nodejs console and type the following;

```
var web3=require('ethereum.js')
var client = require('net')
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.IpcProvider('ipc:.geth.ipc', client);
```

All I get is `...`.

Below works fine for RPC

```
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://someip:8545"));
```

The path `C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum` is empty

Comment: This Might Help:
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3393/why-cant-i-connect-by-ipc

Comment: You're missing a bracket after `client)`,  hence,  `...`,  waiting for user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a bracket after `client)`,  hence,  `...`,  waiting for user input.

```
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.IpcProvider('ipc:.geth.ipc', client);
```

should be

```
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.IpcProvider('ipc:.geth.ipc', client));
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in Windows and web3 v0.20

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const net = require('net');

const client = net.Socket();
const ipcNode = '\\\\.\\pipe\\geth.ipc';

const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.IpcProvider(ipcNode, client));
```