# How can I connect to public chain using web3?

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation, json-rpc

I have used web3 to interact with my private chain by using :

```
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8012"));
```

But How can I connect to Public Network using web3?

I am trying to make a web interface for interaction with my contract( which deployes, where you can use all the functions provided by my contract using my web interface. I have done this on private network and everything worked seamlessly. 
But now I have doubt that whether I can replicate same on public network.
For example let my contract address be `x` and contract ABI be `y` and I have a function named `transfer` to transfer coins. I have done this on private network:

```
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8012"));
var contract1=web3.eth.contract(y).at(x);
contract1.transfer(to, amount, {from: frm});
```

Also can I unlock my account using RPC ? I mean if my users want to create an address, If I can ask for password from them and use `web3.personal.newAccount(password);`.

To summarise:

1. Can I access my contract on Public network using web3? If yes, How?
2. Is `personal` exposed over RPC? I mean if I have to generate addresses or unlock account using web3, how can I do that?
3. There are api that provide Ethereum addresses, how do they work?

Comment: Answer to the question about the `personal` API: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/how-can-i-make-new-account-by-json-rpc. Also, your clients should be managing their own keys; you shouldn't have access to them

Answer (score 9):

This is how you access ehtereum public network

```
new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://api.myetherapi.com/eth')
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Yes, you can access to your contract on the Ethereum mainnet or testnet (public chains) after publishing a contract, exactly like you do for the private chain. 
   You have to connect your client code (Web3 JS) to a running Ethereum node through RPC.
   This running node can be:

   - A node running locally on the client machine (http://localhost:8545)
   - A remote node (provided by your organisation)
   - A 3rd party node
2. Personal is not exposed. The accounts and transactions are handled most of the time by an Ethereum browser such as [Mist](https://github.com/ethereum/mist) or Google Chome (+plugin [Metamask](https://metamask.io/)). The Ethereum browser allows to:

   - Connect to a node
   - Create an account
   - Fund an account
   - Send transaction

For example, every time your client will try to execute a sendTransaction or a contract written functions like you wrote

```
var contract1=web3.eth.contract(y).at(x);
contract1.transfer(to, amount, {from: frm});
```

it will open a popup asking the user to approve the transaction.

Examples of [Metamask](https://metamask.io/)

[image] [image]

3. If you want to manage yourself all this part, I haven't tried but I guess you can use a library like [eth-lightwallet](https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So if I want to write an api to generate ethereum addresses or carry out transactions, the only way I have is to connect to ethereum node via IPC, right? I am not sure if web3_extended can help? Does web3_extended provides support of using perosnal?

Comment: Also if I can't unlock account via RPC, how can I use web3 to connect to a ethereum node voia IPC. Please update the answer. Thanks