# How to connect to infura and deploy contract use web3.py？

Tags: web3.py, infura

the orgin question is below:

```
How to connect to Ropston and deploy contract use web3.py？
I have deploy a contract to Ropston use remix and MetaMask.
I want know how to deploy a contract to Ropston via infura using web3.py without geth or parity.
I read the Documention and find there is no how-to chapter.
A small demo code will be very helpful.
```

And I just search and try And find this code can work.
But, `buildTransaction()`function can't add args `to` and `nonce` (will get error`ValueError: Cannot set nonce in transaction`) And if I just not add `to` `nonce` to transaction  in `signTransaction()` function I will get `errorTypeError: Not all fields initialized`

**There must be something wrong.**
I guess I should use another function rather than `buildTransaction()` But I can't find it in document.

**So, what function I should use?
And what's pythonic way to deploy contract to https://ropsten.infura.io/ ?**

```
from eth_account import Account
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider
from solc import compile_source

privateKey = "xxxxxx"
contract_source_code = '''
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Greeter {
    string public greeting;

    function Greeter() {
        greeting = 'Hello';
    }

    function setGreeting(string _greeting) public {
        greeting = _greeting;
    }

    function greet() constant returns (string) {
        return greeting;
    }
}
'''

compiled_sol = compile_source(contract_source_code)
contract_interface = compiled_sol['<stdin>:Greeter']
w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/"))
w3.eth.enable_unaudited_features()
account = Account()
acct = account.privateKeyToAccount(privateKey)
contract_ = w3.eth.contract(abi=contract_interface['abi'], bytecode=contract_interface['bin'])
contract_data = contract_.constructor().buildTransaction({'from': acct.address,
                                                          'gas': 1728712,
                                                          'gasPrice': w3.toWei('21', 'gwei')})
contract_data["to"] = ""  # <----
contract_data["nonce"] = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(acct.address)   #<------
signed = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(contract_data, privateKey)
w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed.rawTransaction)
```

Comment: You can do it using [eth-testrpc](https://github.com/pipermerriam/eth-testrpc)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of `v4.2.1`, deploying a contract with a local key is a lot more straightforward.

From the question's example code, here is a new approach:

```
w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/YOUR_PROJECT_ID"))

contract_ = w3.eth.contract(
    abi=contract_interface['abi'],
    bytecode=contract_interface['bin'])

acct = w3.eth.account.privateKeyToAccount(privateKey)

construct_txn = contract_.constructor().buildTransaction({
    'from': acct.address,
    'nonce': w3.eth.getTransactionCount(acct.address),
    'gas': 1728712,
    'gasPrice': w3.toWei('21', 'gwei')})

signed = acct.signTransaction(construct_txn)

w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed.rawTransaction)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `web3.py` version `4.2.1`, you can do something like this to deploy your contract through `infura` nodes:

```
from web3 import Web3

class DeployContract:
    def __init__(self, abi, bin, public_key, private_key):
        provider = 'https://ropsten.infura.io/YOUR_INFURA_KEY'
        self.w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(provider))
        self.abi = abi # Your contract ABI code
        self.bin = bin # Your contract ByteCode 
        self.priv = private_key
        self.pub = public_key

    def deploy(self):
        instance = self.w3.eth.contract(abi=self.abi, bytecode=self.bin)
        # hacky .. but it works :D
        tx_data = instance.constructor().__dict__.get('data_in_transaction')
        transaction = {
            'from': self.pub, # Only 'from' address, don't insert 'to' address
            'value': 0, # Add how many ethers you'll transfer during the deploy
            'gas': 2000000, # Trying to make it dynamic ..
            'gasPrice': self.w3.eth.gasPrice, # Get Gas Price
            'nonce': self.w3.eth.getTransactionCount(self.pub), # Get Nonce
            'data': tx_data # Here is the data sent through the network
        }
        # Sign the transaction using your private key
        signed = self.w3.eth.account.signTransaction(transaction, self.priv)
        #print(signed.rawTransaction)
        tx_hash = self.w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed.rawTransaction)
        print(tx_hash.hex())
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have access to a node in all cases. Citing web3.py Read the docs:

> You can connect to your Ethereum node (for example: geth or parity)
>   using one of the available Providers, typically IPC or HTTP.
>
> If your node is running locally, IPC will be faster and safer to
>   expose. If sharing the node across machines on a network, use HTTP
>   instead.
>   Blockquote

So you need to connect to apublic node, for example (taken from [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10574/how-can-i-connect-to-public-chain-using-web3)):

```
w3 = Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://api.myetherapi.com/eth')
```

Then you can do your magic with w3!. However, the main issue here is how to manage your keys myetherapi does not allow methods that involve account.

Note: I have not used myetherapi.com!

I hope this help.

Comment: you are right,I have run some code using geth.But in this project,I have to use infura. I want to know how to do it.