# Create new account over IPC

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts, ipc

I want to create a new account over IPC so I have started private chain with the below command

```
geth --networkid=5 --datadir DataDir --ipcapi "db,eth,net,web3,personal" --ipcpath "/Users/smartSense/.ethereum/geth.ipc"
--rpc -rpcapi "eth,web3" --rpcaddr=localhost --rpcport=8545 --rpccorsdomain "*" console 2>geth.log
```

now I'm trying to create new account with web3 api Ref. Link : [Link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/how-can-i-make-new-account-by-json-rpc?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
var options = {
    host: '/Users/smartSense/.ethereum/geth.ipc',
    ipc:true,
    personal: true,
    admin: false,
    debug: false
};

var web3Extended = web3_extended.create(options);
web3Extended.personal.newAccount("password",function(error,result){
        if (!error)
            res.send(result);
        else
            res.send("error"+error);
});
```

but I got below error:

```
errorError: Invalid JSON RPC response: "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80\n    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
\n    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1045:20)\n    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1090:14)"
```

over RPC I have created successfully but over IPC i got error so any one have idea about that?

Comment: Try using this `var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.IpcProvider('/Users/myuser/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc', net));`

Answer (score 0):

Require `web3_ipc` instead of `web3_extended`.

`const web3_extended = require('web3_ipc');`

Also, make sure your geth.ipc location is right. Mine (Mac OS X) was on ~/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc.