# geth setup on aws for custom wallet application

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, aws

I need to create an app that will hold custom wallet per user, I was using Infura earlier, but now I have to create wallets so will need "Personal" on rpc. I see that Infura don't expose it so will need my own private node.
How can I setup personal node on AWS with bare minimum configurations so thats I don't need more storage and computing power.

If some one can explain the steps and also things to do, it will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have setup several nodes in AWS.

1. Launch an Ubuntu instance
2. When you have ssh'ed in and at the terminal type the following one by one

-

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common

sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install ethereum
```

once you have that done you should be able to type: geth

I expect yo know how to start geth with the right parameters to enable --rpc and personal.

** Make sure you open the correct ports in your AWS Security group.

** Min spec,  a dual core cpu, min 2GB RAM, as large a hard drive as you can afford.  If your using this for production I would personally put 500gb to allow room for growth.

Alternatively you can download directly from the source and build.  When at the terminal do the following.

```
git clone https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum.git
cd go-ethereum
make geth
```

In this video I created on how to mine Eth on GPUs in Amazon shows you the steps I took above ^ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UUQ9UW6f5Dg

resources

https://geth.ethereum.org/install/

https://www.ethereum.org/cli

Answer (score 0):

My strong advice is to **not** enable `personal` API over RPC. On the geth wiki at https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#personal, it says:

> The personal API manages private keys in the key store.

You do **not** want to expose it to other nodes. The code calling `personal` API methods should be running locally on the node and should be able to use IPC.

For more details, see the accepted answer to the question linked below.

[How can I make new account by JSON-RPC?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/how-can-i-make-new-account-by-json-rpc#acceptedAnswer)