# create ethereum wallet in Api

Tags: wallets

I want to create an Ethereum wallet, and I need an address and a private key, but I am unable to generate both. Please suggest a way to generate key pairs.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new account with JSON RPC makes the client handle the keystore. Usually it's saved in a `.json` file locally.

Check this question about how to create a new account, but note that the private key will not be returned.

[How can I make new account by JSON-RPC?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/how-can-i-make-new-account-by-json-rpc)

If you want to create a wallet and have access to the private key, the [go-ethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum) client might be useful.
Use the libraries directly and generate your own wallets.

For example import the crypto library

```
import "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto"
```

And generate your account

```
key, err := crypto.GenerateKey()
```

To get the private key do

```
hex.EncodeToString(key.D.Bytes())
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to generate address and private key in Node.js/javascript you can use `web3-eth-accounts` package

```
const Accounts = require('web3-eth-accounts');

const accounts = new Accounts('http://localhost:8545');
const { address, privateKey } = accounts.create();
```