# Create accounts on ethereum network using programmatically generated key pairs and addresses

Tags: javascript, addresses, nodejs

Say I have a node application that has user registration feature. Now when a user registers,  using node libraries like `crypto` I  generate a cryptographic key pair(private and public).  Then also generate an address from the public key just mentioned. My question is, is there a way to programmatically create Externally owned accounts with these key pairs and addresses. Such that these addresses can now be valid wallet addresses on the ethereum network? 
Don’t know if my question would sound too basic or so, but searching for clarity. Any beginner friend response will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are two types of accounts in Ethereum
>
> - Externally Owned Accounts
> - Contracts Accounts

Not sure that I understood it right, but correct me if I wrong. You've created private key and address of account. Am I right? If yes, you created Externally Owned Accounts.

There is another way to create account:
[create ethereum wallet in Api](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/38972/create-ethereum-wallet-in-api/59711#59711)