# Eth wallet keywords api

Tags: wallets

How can I create an ethereum wallet and get the 12 key words by using the ethereum rpc? I cannot find the rpc api.

Comment: Which type of node (e.g., Geth, Parity, etc)?

Comment: Answer to a related question [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/how-can-i-make-new-account-by-json-rpc)